# Finding the roots of an implicit function with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve numerically the following implicit equation, using Python:

```
y*sin(c)+sin(y*c)=0
```

where `c` is a constant. How would you suggest me to do that? I implemented the classical Newton-Raphson's method, but it doesn't seem to converge.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code:

```
f = open('results.dat','w')

import math

alpha = input('Define the alpha angle: ')

print >> f, 'alpha =', alpha

lambda_0 = input('Define an initial value: ')

print >> f, 'y_0 = ', y_0

gamma = math.pi - math.radians(alpha)

# def f(x,y):
#   p = 2.0 * x
#   t = p * y
#   val  = t * math.cos(t) - math.sin(t)
#   val /= (p * math.cos(t) + math.sin(p))
#   return val

toll = 1e-12

itmax = 50

diff = 1.0

it = 0

while diff > toll and it <= itmax:
    p = 2.0 * gamma
    t = p * y_0
    y_1  = t * math.cos(t) - math.sin(t)
    y_1 /= (p * math.cos(t) + math.sin(p))

    print >> f, 'p = ', p

    print >> f, 't = ', t

    print >> f, 'y at iteration ', it, ' = ', y

    diff = abs(y - y_0)
    y_0 = y
    it += 1

    print >> f, 'diff = ', diff

    print >> f, 'y_0 = ', y_0

    print >> f, 'it = ', it

f.close()
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Comment: How have you defined convergence? What criteria are you using?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Sorry for the delay, I added the code.

Comment: @PhilH: I define a desired tolerance of the difference of the results between two successive iterations (now you posted also my code).

Answer (score 2):

If Newton raphson is not working, perhaps you should try something simple like [Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) . Time complexity is still in the order of O(n) where n is the number of bits of precision.

Comment: Note: Newton-Raphson is quadratic in convergence when it converges, which is better than Bisection method. If you want something as robust as bisection but with similar convergence properties to NR, the you may want the secant method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your solution: y=0

Maybe you mean a non-zero solution? Or something else?

EDIT: Adding something a bit more useful

### Transformation to a nicer form

Assuming that you need the first positive solution you can do the following:

Transform coordinates using `z=y*c` which gives the equation:

```
 A*z = sin(z)
```

Where `A = -sin(c)/c`.

This is determining the intersection of a line through the origin of slope A with the normal sine curve.

If you draw a diagram of this you will see that for `|A| >= 1` there will only be the `z=0` solution.

Part of the problem with getting your method to converge to the right root is to pick starting values near the root. In this case we can approximate these roots.

### Critical slope case  (|A|~1)

For `|A|` near 1 we can see that there will be a positive and negative solution near 0. We can approximate these using a low order Taylor series for sine.

```
A*z = z - z^3/6 + ...
```

Approximate solutions to this are z=0,  `z=R` and `z=-R` where `R=sqrt( 6 (1-A) )`.
This suggests that for `|A|` near 1 a good starting place for numerical estimation is:

```
y=(1/c) sqrt( (6/c)( 1 + sin(c) ) )
```

### Small slope case ( |A|~0 )

For small A we expect a solution near `pi`.  In this case we do a further change of variables `z=p+pi`.

```
 A (p + pi) = sin( p + pi ) = -sin(p)
```

Expading sin again gives us:

```
A p  + A pi = -p + ...
```

This gives an approximate solution of:

```
p = - A pi / (A+1)
```

Which simplifies to

```
z = pi/(A+1)
```

This means we should look for a starting point of

```
y = pi/(c(A+1))
```

### Using the approximations

I'd probably pick a starting point by blending those two values using linear interpolation.

You can also do a similar expansion near `A = 2/pi` for "intermediate" values, and use three points in your linear interpolation.

Starting from these apprimxations may be enough to get Newtons method to converge to the desired value. However if you really need to ensure convergence to the right root, you'll probably need to drop Newton-Raphson and use these values as a starting point for the secant or bisection methods.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm looking for the first non-zero solution. I don't understand clearly how I should implement the code, can you show me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2asin%28c%29%2Bsin%28y%2ac%29%3D0+where+c%3D8) is your curve for a random c (8).

It has infinite solutions as far as I can see so finding one wont be too hard. Take a look at scipy for a well written Raphson-Newton (your code is probably wrong). Look here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

Comment: His code isn't necessarily wrong, as Newton-Raphson isn't guaranteed to converge (and it isn't just trivial cases where convergence fails). Make sure to try multiple starting values for your algorithm to make sure it isn't a local issue.

Comment: I don't really know how his code is, it's just an assumption given such a solution-ful curve! well, it's easy to see that when lim y->0 y*sin(c) + sin(y*c) will always equal zero (whatever c), so at least in a neighborhood of 0 it should converge. Still you need to pick up an interval not too far from a 0.

Comment: There aren't infinitely many! (For any fixed `c` with `sin(c) ≠ 0`, anyway.) `sin` has range [-1, 1], so zeros require `|y| * |sin(c)| <= 1`, i.e. are only possible when `|y| < 1 / |sin(c)|`.